# Size of MAXCUT from eigenvalues

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, max-cut

Is there an interpretation of MAXCUT using eigenvalues of the graph that yields constant factor approximation to MAXCUT?

Can the estimates provide sharp lower bound to MAXCUT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection between the spectrum of the graph and the size of the maximum cut. It might be easiest to see this with the normalized graph Laplacian, $L = I - D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$, where $I$ is the identity, $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph $G = ([n], E)$, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix defined by $D_{ii} = d_i$, the degree of vertex $i$. The largest eigenvalue of $L$ is

$$\lambda_{n-1} = \max_x\frac{x^TLx}{x^Tx} = \max_{x}\frac{\sum_{(i, j) \in E}{(x_i - x_j)^2}}{\sum_{i}{d_i x_i^2}}.$$

Because $(x_i - x_j)^2 \leq 2x_i^2 + 2x_j^2$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, $\lambda_{n-1} \leq 2$. Equality is achieved if and only if for each edge $(i, j)$, $x_i = -x_j$, which means that $\lambda_{n-1}= 2$ only if the graph has a bipartite connected component, i.e. a connected component whose maximum cut is equal to the number of edges in the component.

For a robust version of this result, see [Luca Trevisan's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1978). He showed that

$$
\lambda_{n-1} \geq 2\frac{\text{MaxCut}}{m},
$$

(where $m$ is the number of edges of the graph) and if $\lambda_{n-1} \geq 2(1-\epsilon)$, then there exits a set of vertices $S$ and a partition $(S_1, S_2)$ of $S$ such that

$$
|e(S_1, S_2)| \geq \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{16\epsilon})\text{vol}(S),
$$
where $\text{vol}(S) = \sum_{i \in S}{d_i}$ and $e(S_1, S_2)$ is the set of edges with one endpoint in $S_1$ and the other in $S_2$.

Note that the second bound does not necessarily lower bound the max cut in a useful way: it only lower bounds the maximum cut of the set $S$ *in terms of $\text{vol}(S)$*. This is unavoidable: think of a graph that is the disjoint union of an edge and a large graph with small maximum cut, say a clique. The maximum cut of the graph is very close to $m/2$, which is the minimum possible value of the max cut of a graph with $m$ edges. However, $\lambda_{n-1} = 2$, the maximum possible value of $\lambda_{n-1}$. In other words, while $\lambda_{n-1}$ is a relaxation of the maximum cut (up to appropriate rescaling), the gap is arbitrarily close to 2, and a 2-approximation to max cut is trivial.

Nevertheless, in the paper Luca uses the spectral result to design a recursive approximation algorithm for max cut. This is one cool thing about the paper: it uses a relaxation that, unlike the SDP relaxation of Goemans and Williamson, has trivial gap, but despite that an optimal solution to the relaxation actually provides enough guidance to achieve a non-trivial approximation factor.

Comment: Thankyou. What is $m$? what is $e(S_1,S_2)$ here? And so we have $MaxCut \leq \frac{\lambda_{n-1}}{2m}$?

Comment: Can we have a lower bound to $MaxCut$ from eignevalues?

Comment: I think you did the algebra wrong there, the max cut is at most $m \lambda_{n-1}/2$. This is the easy direction however. Indeed, the second bound is a partial converse. Note that it only says something about the subset $S$, however. In general you cannot lower bound the maximum cut of the entire graph from $\lambda_{n-1}$ because it's possible to have $\lambda_{n-1} = 2$ but the maximum cut being arbitrarily close to its minimum possible value, $m/2$

Comment: I see that $MaxCut*d_{max}\geq|e(S_1,S_2)|$ and hence $MaxCut\geq\frac{1}{2d_{max}}(1-\sqrt{16\epsilon})Vol(S)$. Is this a sharp lower bound? However there is no eigenvalue here.

Comment: Correction: $MaxCut\leq\frac{m\lambda_{n-1}}{2}$ holds.

Comment: "In general you cannot lower bound the maximum cut of the entire graph from λn−1" How about for regular graphs or some graphs with special structure?>

Comment: Does your updated comment hold for connected graphs with $\lambda_{n-1}<2$? You have mentioned disjoint union as a counter example to my lower bound estimate.

Comment: as long as you allow a graph that consists of a large graph with small maximum cut and a small bipartite graph, and the two are either disconnected or are connected by a small number of edges, the gap between $2m - 2\text{MaxCut}$ and $2 - \lambda_{n-1}$ can be arbitrarily bad. however, I'd say Luca's partial converse is quite satisfactory.

Comment: I am interested in a graph sequence that is regular and is not bipartite which also has $MaxCut=\theta(n)$ in my case. That is why I thought may be your comments could be turned into a sharp lowerbound and am I wrong again?

Comment: So the bad example is quite robust. It's not necessary to have a bipartite connected component: just a small set of vertices that induce a subgraph which is *close to bipartite* and the cut between these vertices and the rest of the graph is small.

Comment: It seems that $m = O(n^2)$. Does it really give a constant fact result since $\frac{\lambda_{n-1}}{2}\leq 1$?

Comment: The result here http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Reprints/1990/BM90_CMJ40_Delorme_MaximumCutProblem.pdf gives $\frac{n\lambda_{n-1}}{4}$. May be it is the way the Laplacians arew defined?

Comment: About Delorme-Poljak, the difference is because their Laplacian is not normalized, so it is equal to mine muliplied by $D^{1/2}$ on both sides. With respect to your first question, I do not understand what you are asking. Think of $\lambda_{n-1}m/2$ as the relaxation of MaxCut. If the graph is bipartite, $\lambda_{n-1} = 2$. Fan Chung's notes are a good source about basic spectral graph theory: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/cb/ch1.pdf

Comment: nevermind, the first question was related to the second. You answer answers both.

Comment: BTW the Delorme-Poljak bound is stronger than the largest eigenvalue of the laplacian and is in fact equivalent to the Goemans-Williamson SDP.

Comment: How is it stronger? Symbolically both look the same except for the factor of $4$ below and the modified Laplacians?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10867/discussion-between-sasho-nikolov-and-jas)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The original [Goemans-Williamson paper](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/maxcut-jacm.pdf) also discusses the dual of the PSD relaxation, which is equivalent to minimizing $\lambda_{max}(L_G+D)$, over all the traceless diagonal matrices D.

[Trevisan](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1978v5.pdf) used some of this intuition to design a nontrivial approximation to MaxCut, at the bottom of which lies a spectral partitioning algorithm. In his algorithm, he essentially looks at the largest eigenvector of the normalized Laplacian in order to isolate components of the graph between which there is a large cut. The core of the analysis is a Cheeger-like inequality for the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: "....all traceless" contains complex matrices?

Comment: No, we're only looking at real matrices.

Comment: I think since L is real, D the optimal D will be real wlog